# Question about Automorphism group being isomorphic to S_n

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x) \in k[x]$ be a separable irreducible polynomial of degree n over a field k, and let F be its splitting field. Assume $Aut_k(F) \cong S_n$ , and let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$ in F. Prove that $Aut_{k(\alpha)}(F) \cong S_{n-1}$.

I am saying that it suffices to prove that $k(\alpha)$ contains no other roots of $f(x)$ since our assumption is that our Automorphism group is the set of all permutations of roots.

Comment: The way I see it automorphisms fixing $k(\alpha)$ is the same as automorphisms fixing k and $\alpha$ which can easily be seen to be $S_{n-1}$ since an element in the galois group fixes $\alpha$ iff $\alpha$ doesn't show up in the cycle decomposition.

Comment: But how do I know that no other root shows up in k($\alpha$)?

Comment: hmm, well you know that no roots appear in k because the polynomial is irreducible. If you adjoint just one root because the polynomial is seperable of degree n you know that by Galois correspondence that the subgroup of S_n has index exactly n and must be S_{n-1}? Is there a classification of groups of order n! being isomorphic to S_{n-1}?

Answer (score 1):

$\textrm{Aut}_k(F) \cong S_n$ consists of every permutation of the roots of $f$. So $\textrm{Aut}_{k(\alpha)}(F)$ is the group of permutations which fix $\alpha$. This is clearly isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$.

Comment: How do we know that $k(\alpha)$ contains no other roots of f?

Comment: That would contradict that $\textrm{Aut}_k(F) \cong S_n$.

Comment: I figured it had to contradict that but I don't see how.

Comment: If $\alpha, \beta$ are distinct roots of $f$ in $k(\alpha)$, then
$$f(x) = (x - \alpha)(x - \beta)g(x)$$
over $k(\alpha)$, where $g(x)$ has degree at most $n - 2$. The tower law then shows that
$$\vert \textrm{Aut}_k(F) \vert \leq (n - 1)!.$$

Comment: $[F: k(\alpha)] = (n-2)!$ and $[k(\alpha): k] \le (n-1)$?

Comment: No. $[k(\alpha) : k] = n$.